# Point syntax in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am using this synatax in matplotlib for define a line.

```
line2, = ax.plot([], [], lw=2, color = 'green', alpha = 0.4)
```

I need also define a point with similar syntax, using ax.plot(). Do you have any idea how to do it?

Thanks.

I tried :

```
point, = ax.plot([])
```

But it is a rubbish.

Comment: What are you trying to plot?

Comment: you need some x and y data.

Comment: I am making animation with matplotlib, and there at first I need to define it, and in every step of animation I set data (points) of my lines, but now I need use only a point, not line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To plot a point, you could use `ax.scatter`:

```
dot = ax.scatter([x], [y], s=130, color='green', alpha=0.4)
```

The `s` parameter allows you to control the size of the dot.

---

If in the animation you wish to change the location of the dot, use

```
dot.set_offsets((newx, newy))
canvas.draw()
```

as changing the offset is quicker than generating a new scatter plot.